# Google Sheets Regex combine with If statement

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Please help me solve the error in my formula.

Data:

Condition 1
Cell A1: `7 x ecobulb-90R (CFL Replace) (bedroom) @ $3`

Condition 2
Cell A1: `7 x ecobulb-90R (CFL Replace) @ $3`

Condition 3
Cell A1: `7 x ecobulb-90R CFL Replace @ $3`

My regex formula that i've used:

```
IF(REGEXMATCH(A1,"x\s((.*) (.*)|(.*)?)\s@"),REGEXREPLACE(A1,$1,"x\s(((.*) (.*)))\s@"),$1)
```

Expected output: if there are no strings enclosed in parenthesis and if there is only one pair of the string enclosed in parenthesis before the `@` symbol get the strings before the `@` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

the correct syntax would be:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(A1, "x\s((.*) (.*)|(.*)?)\s@"), 
 REGEXREPLACE(A1, "x\s(((.*) (.*)))\s@", "$1"), )
```

[image: 0]

tho not sure what are you after because you did not explain yourself

### ___________________________________________________________

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A3, "[A-Za-z\d\s$@-]+", ))<4, 
 REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A3, "(.+) @"), A1:A3))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I want to remove if there is a location enclosed in parenthesis

Comment: Based on your worksheet my expected output should be in cells b2 and b3 only without the price